# How can I specify an optional value in a tasks result selector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I would like to create a dynamodb step using the resource `arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem` where some attributes may not be available.

The relevant portion of my task is as follows:

```json
"Get Config": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
  "Next": "DummyPass",
  "Parameters": {
    "Key": {
      "pk": { "S.$": "$.someKey)" },
      "sk": { "S": "A" }
    },
    "TableName": "test_table"
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.config",
  "ResultSelector": {
    "foo.$": "$.Item.foo.S",
    "bar.$": "$.Item.bar.S"
  },
}
```

Within this task I am attempting to select the DynamoDB typed annotated items and flatten into a JSON structure of just the keys and values.

There appears to not be any intrinsic functions available that could achieve this.

The workaround is to create a lambda, though it defeats the purpose of services now being supported by step functions.

Comment: I wish it was possible to do it in a single step as you suggested, and I'm sure that it will be easier in the future. Until then, you can check the pattern that we use with a `Choice` step as detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73967219/179529

Comment: Thank you @Guy, those are also very valid points in your answer. My problem is that I'm looking for a way to parse the result where `GetItem` might have a sparse result where some of the fields do not exist. This means I can't even do it in a `Pass` because there's no way to specify a field that might not exist. Instead, I've written a lambda that does the unmarshalling and allows me to specify fields that should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this by creating a lambda that exposes [jmespath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmespath) that takes a `Data` and `Expression` attribute:

```js
const jmespath = require("jmespath");

// convenience that ensures correct sync vs async lambda definition.
const { wrappedApply } = require("./lambda-tools.js");

function jmespathHandler (options) {
  return jmespath.search(options.Data, options.Expression);
}

module.exports = {
  jmespathHandler: wrappedApply(jmespathHandler)
};
```

Given an input of the following:

```json
{
  "x": {
    "foo": "FOO",
    "bar": "BAR",
  },
  "y": {
    "bat": "BAT"
  }
}
```

I can now call this function with a definition like:

```json
{
  "Type": "Task"
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
  "End": true,
  "ResultSelector": {
    "FormatOutput.$": "$.Payload"
  },
  "OutputPath": "$.FormatOutput",
  "Parameters": {
    "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME",
    "Payload": {
      "Data.$": "States.JsonMerge($.x, $.y, false)",
      "Expression": "{Foo: foo, Bar: bar, Bat: bat, Baz: baz}"
    }
  },
}
```

Which will now output the following json.

```json
{
  "Foo": "FOO",
  "Bar": "BAR",
  "Bat": "BAT",
  "Baz": null
}
```

You can see here that I've renamed the keys but also included a missing key `Baz` that because selected will become null.

Note that I've demonstrated using `States.JsonMerge` which could have been achieved within jmespath directly, however I just used this to demonstrate another tool you may find useful.

For completeness I'm including `wrappedApply` here:

```js
function wrappedApply (action) {
  if (action.constructor.name === "AsyncFunction") {
    return action;
  }
  /* eslint consistent-return: "off" */
  return function (data, ctx, callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      return action(data, ctx, callback);
    }
    try {
      const res = action(data, ctx, callback);
      callback(null, res);
    } catch (e) {
      callback(e);
    }
  };
}
```

This can then be called to

Answer (score 1):

As for specifying an optional value in result selector - this is currently not natively available from step functions. You could however pass down the entire output into a choice state and condition on that optional value.

For attempting to select the items and flattening into a JSON structure, we also do not yet support this natively, and will have to use a lambda function as you mentioned as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks ehwang, I did consider the `Choice` approach, though I have a few properties I expect to be available and it would get hairy, though probably clever. I did opt to put together a simple JS lambda that pretty much exposes `unmarshall` but with an added options to allow the caller to include missing fields. Will include it here when I've finished testing.